# Count number of words in a cell that are in a range

Tags: excel

In one column I have phrases e.g. `Peanut butter jelly time`. I need to know how many words in a range (e.g. B:B) appear in each phrase. It would be awesome to know **which** words are in the range. Case doesn't matter.

Ideally, the output would look like:

**Phrase--------------------------NumOfWords----------------Words**

Peanut butter jelly time----------2-----------------------------butter, time

Wayne's World-------------------1-----------------------------world

I have tried various formulas, both array and non-array, and some UDFs.

Would prefer a non-VBA solution, since I'm still a novice, but any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want non-VBA?  This can be done quite easily in VBA!

Comment: I am slightly confused as to what you want.  Do you want the number of words occurring in the phrase?  So Peanut butter jelly time would return 4.  Or are you looking for the number of occurrences of words in the Words column that occur in the Phrase?  This would equate to 2 as you have in your example.

Comment: Hiya :)

What I want is, if I have a list of words e.g. (butter, time, world, frog, laptop), to know how many of those words appear in each phrase, and which words. If you can do it in VBA that's awesome - just don't know if I have the expertise to implement it.

Comment: If the word appears **twice** should it be counted as **2** ??

Comment: Nope- once is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following **User Defined Function** *(UDF)*:

```
Public Function WordCounter(phrase As String, llist As String) As Long
    Dim s As String, sp As String
    Dim mtch As String
    WordCounter = 0
    sp = " "
    s = sp & LCase(Trim(phrase)) & sp
    ary = Split(Replace(llist, " ", ""), ",")
    For Each a In ary
        mtch = sp & a & sp
        If InStr(1, s, mtch) > 0 Then
            WordCounter = WordCounter + 1
        End If
    Next a
End Function
```

The space-padding is used to avoid matching parts of words.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

**=WordCounter(A1,C1)**

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Your example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but its a no-go. I'm not trying to count the words in C1 -  I'm trying to count the words in a range on another sheet (e.g. 'Sheet2"B2:B245). I tried naming that range and still no luck. When I try =WordCount(A1234, 'Sheet2"B2:B245) or =WordCount(A1234, list)  I get a value error. C1  should be the words in 'Sheet2"B2:B245 that appear in A1. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: @AngelDesjarlais  I will fix this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

For a possible non-VBA solution, try the following:

- Phrases are in Column A
- WordList is a `named range` that contains a list of single words that you want to determine if they are in the phrase in a particular cell in Column A.

For the number of matching words, try this formula:

**EDIT:**  formulas edited to eliminate partial matches.

```
B2:   =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" " & WordList & " "," " & A2 & " ")))
```

For the individual matching words, try this `array-entered` formula.  (To `array-enter` a formula, hold down `ctrl+shift` when you hit `enter` to confirm the formula.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula:

```
C2:   =IFERROR(INDEX(" " & WordList & " ",SMALL(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" " & WordList & " "," " & $A2 & " "))*ROW(WordList),COLUMNS($A:A)+SUM(--NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" " & WordList & " "," " & $A2 & " ")))))),"")
```

Then select C2 and fill right for at least as many cells as there are words to return, or until the formula returns blanks.  Then select the cells you just filled, and fill down as far as required.

### Notes

- The formulas in C2 and rightward will only work if the range WordList begins with the first word in Row 1 (could be in any column on any worksheet, but needs to start with Row 1).  If it starts at a different row, the `Row(WordList)` part will need to be adjusted accordingly.
- If you want a **case-sensitive** match, replace SEARCH with FIND in the above formulas

This is the results, using the above formulas:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ron - thanks for the formulas! Your first one is almost there, but not quite. The trouble with the list I'm searching is that it may contain partial matches with the cell, e.g. it could be "butter, butte, time, tim" etc., and I need to know how many exact matches there are. Do you have a way of fixing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a limit to the # of words to look up? If so, a solution (ugly, but avoids VBA) is to use hidden columns on the right to check if each word from Sheet2 is found, and B1 would simply add up those that are.